# serial communication write() doesn't work always

Tags: c, terminal, serial-port, raspberry-pi3

I have a problem that I can't seem to figure out :

I have a serial communication through Bluetooth between my RPi and my PC with Putty.
I use the following code to send text from my RPi to Putty :

```
ssize_t serial::writeSerialPort(char const *string)
{
    /*
     write a string to the serial connection
     */

    ssize_t result = write(fd, string, strlen(string));

    tcflush(fd, TCOFLUSH);
    if (result != strlen(string))
        printf("Failed to write to serial port!\n");
    else
        printf("Wrote to serial port!\n");

    return result;
}
```

The strange thing now is that sometimes the text is being send to Putty and that works a while.
Then suddenly it stops working, after a while it starts working again (all in the same session).

When I set a breakpoint and debug my code the text is always being outputted right after the `write()` function (before the `tcflush()` ).

This of course makes it hard to find out why I have this "bug".

The result is always equal to `strlen(string)` so I'm pretty sure that it was correctly written.
Anyone that can point me in the right direction?

Comment: C doesn't have `::`. Are you sure you're not programming in C++.

Comment: I exchanged the tcflush() with tcdrain() and now it is working correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you want to achieve by `tcflush(fd, TCOFLUSH);`. That function call specifically **discards** - i.e. puts into trash can - all data written to `fd`, but not yet sent over the serial link.

Quoting [Linux manuals](https://linux.die.net/man/3/tcflush):

> `tcflush()` ***discards*** data written to the object referred to by `fd` but not transmitted, or data received but not read, depending on the value of `queue_selector`:
>
> - `TCOFLUSH`
>
>   flushes data written but not transmitted.

---

Perhaps you wanted to use [`tcdrain()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/tcflush) instead:

> `tcdrain()` waits until all output written to the object referred to by `fd` **has been transmitted.**